# How to save more than one classess in same package in java for beginners?

Tags: java, package

I am beginner in Java and I made package World then write a simple source code as you can see it.

```
package World; 

class Argument { 

    public static void main(String []args) { 
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }

}
```

Now i wrote command in cmd as `javac -d . Argument`. It compiles successfully. 
Then i wrote command in cmd as `java World.Argument`.
It works Perfectly. Now i want to know how to store more than one classess in same package?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Whats your opinion on CMD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compile multiple classes just do:

`javac *.java`

Or if you want to specify files manually:

`javac Argument.java OtherFile.java`

Comment: Thanks for feedback! I am confuse in between how to save multiple classess in same package .

Comment: Create a new file in the same directory as your `Argument` file.